# Able to access elasticsearch without credential on production after installing elasticsearch-http-user-auth plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I am able to access elastic search without a credential on production, the same thing I tried on Dev/stage instances there worked fine.

**On Dev**

```
Elasticsearch v 5.1.2
Elasticsearch-http-user-auth v5.1.2
java version "1.8.0_45"
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: APP
node.name: node1

network.host: [server_1_ip, local]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [server_1_ip, server_2_ip]
elasticfence.disabled: false
elasticfence.root.password: root
```

ES API Call

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Response: Needs Basic Auth

curl -u root:root http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Response: json data
```

**On Production**

```
Elasticsearch v 5.1.2
Elasticsearch-http-user-auth v5.1.2
java version "1.8.0_111"
```

elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: APP
node.name: node1

network.host: [server_1_ip, local]
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [server_1_ip, server_2_ip]

elasticfence.disabled: false
elasticfence.root.password: root
```

ES API Call

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Response: JSON data
Actual I should get 'Needs Basic Auth'

curl -u root:root http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
Response: JSON data
```

created an issue in [github](https://github.com/elasticfence/elasticsearch-http-user-auth/issues/69).

**Questions?**

Did I miss any configuration?

Please help me to solve this problem